# list files created or updated on a specific day

Tags: linux, ls

Wondering what is the most simple command to show (ls) local files under a specific folder created or updated on a specific day?

I am using Linux/Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -t
```

Will sort results based on date.

Comment: I know this option and wondering how to filter to show only a specific day (by create time or update time). My folder contains so many fils and it is why I ask the option here. :)

Comment: @Lin Ma You can use grep. ls -t  | grep 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: I think you mean ls -lt? -t itself does not output date to grep for.